# Laravel XML download not right export

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I'm still learning Laravel 5.3 and am using Guzzle to connect to an API to download an already formatted xml file that I need to save to local user's pc for further usage.
I have created a download button:

```
    <a href="{{ '/vendorOrder' }}" class="btn btn-large pull-right> Download Order </a>
```

I created a controller called OrderController.php:

```
    <?php
     namespace App\Http\Controllers\edi;

     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
     use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
     use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;

     class OrderController extends Controller
     {
          public function vendorOrder()
          {
              try {
                   $filename = 'order.xml';
                   $path = storage_path($filename)';

                   $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
                   $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', 'Https://urlapi') [
                   'headers' => [
                       'Authorization' => 'Basic QVBJVGVzdFVzZXIsIFdlbGNvbWVAMTIz',
                       'ContractID' => 'aa659aa2-4175-471f',
                       'Accept' => 'text/xml'
                   ],
                   ]);

               $content = ($apiRequest->getBody()->getContents());

               return response::download(file_put_contents($path, $content), '200', [
               'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
               'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'
             ]);

              } catch (RequestException $re) {
                 echo $re;
              }
           }
       }
```

and the route:

```
    Route::get('/vendorOrder', 'edi\OrderController@vendorOrder');
```

I'm able to connect just fine, and the contents of the xml display just fine  when I use:

```
    return response($content, '200')->header('content-type', 'text/xml');
```

however when I use:

```
    return response::make(file_put_contents($path, $content), '200', [
            'Content-Type' =>  'text/xml',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'
        ]);
```

as in controller above, I'm able to download a file called order.xml (as expected) but the contents is just a single number ie "1179866".  No xml tags or the xml content or anything else - just the number.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked value of `$content` variable?

Comment: echo $content shows contents of xml file as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you are wrong.

1. `response::download` 
   What are the arguments to `response::download`?
   See a manual:

> `Response::download($pathToFile);`

See - **path to file**. In your code:

```
return response::download(file_put_contents($path, $content), // other arguments
```

result of `file_put_contents` is **not** a path to file.

Read a [manual](http://php.net/file_put_contents) and see that `file_put_contents`

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

Solution:

```
$path = 'my/path/here';
file_put_contents($path, $content);
return response::download($path, // other arguments
```

2. `response::make`. Same error.

See a manual:

> `response::make($contents, $statusCode);`

Again - first argument is `$contents`.

In your code

```
response::make(file_put_contents($path, $content),
```

contents if the result of `file_put_contents` execution, which is see above.

Solution:

```
response::make($content, 200, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works perfectly with your suggested solutions